# Why is a Rails form_tag displaying an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Using Rails 3/Ruby 1.9.3, I have to dynamically generate a form using an array of values.  The form generates properly with the exception that the `@sub_fields` array is being output to the screen between the form values and the submit button.

The HAML code that generates the form looks like this:

```
= form_tag "/magazine/subscribers" do
  = @sub_fields.each do |k,v|
    .formField
      - if v.has_key? :evaluate
        = label_tag k.to_s, v[:label_text]
        = v[:evaluate].call(k)
      - else
        - unless v[:input_type] == :hidden_field
          = label_tag k, v[:label_text]
        - if v[:select_options]
          = select_tag(k, options_for_select(v[:select_options].call))
        - else
          = eval(v[:input_type].to_s + "_tag '#{v[:value].to_s}'")
      - if v.has_key? :tooltip
        .fieldTip
          %ul
            - v[:tooltip].each do |tip|
              %li= tip

  .formAction
    = submit_tag "localize edit"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use - instead of =

```
- @sub_fields.each do |k,v|
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your expedient response!

Comment: Glad I could help!